# Иероглифы в автокомплите Sublime 3

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

На работе с DE xfce4(Fedora 23) - всё ок, 20 gnome дома (Fedora 24) - вот такая штука
Проблема в чём может быть?

[image: иерогрлифы в автокомплите]

Comment: шрифты не встали. Верни стандартную тему, ошибка повторяться будет?

Comment: в системе, или sublime? в редакторе ставил дефолтные - тоже самое

Comment: ну, в стандартной теме, повторяется ошибка?

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев повторяется

Comment: значит в систему не встали нужные шрифты. Надо искать :)

Comment: Это не иероглифы, это инщикаторы отсутствующих символов, да.

Comment: @K.Lobastov у меня такая же проблема, пропали символы на некоторых сайтах. Посмотрел по исходникам, там использовались 2 шрифта `verdana` и `arial`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ипользуя тиблицу символов в системе, убедился, что нет ниодного шрифта в системе из категории "Символы и знаки препинания CJK" для символов `U+3014` и `U+3015`

[Тут](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3014/fontsupport.htm) можно найти список шрифтов, в котором имеется этот символ, я установил `unifont`, перезапустил sublime и всё ок.